# Joomla! 2.5 and Virtuemart 2.0.18a $.facebox is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla2.5, virtuemart, facebox

I'm using Joomla! 2.5.8 and Virtuemart 2.0.18a and on Add to Cart I got "Typeerror $.facebox is undefined in vmprices.js (line 67)". When I changed my Joomla! Template to default I lost this error. Many researches gives that jQuery loads any time, but when I disabled VirtueMart jQuery, I've got an error that "jQuery is undefined".

My site is http://bestgifts.am

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is work and for J1.5 + V2.0

Answer (score 0):

The reason is  , you have multiple jquery includes by plugin or templates..

The quickest fix for facebox undefined error is include this code just before closing the body tag inside your template..

< script type="text/javascript" src="your_site_url/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/facebox.js">

It works for me..

Dont forget to remove spaces from script tags..